# How to print a datagridview where each row is printed in a new page?

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

I have a datagridview table with information

```
a | b
--+--
3 | 3
4 | 4
5 | 5
```

How can I use the print functionalities in c# to print 3,3 in page one and 4,4 in page 2, 5,5 in page 3 and so on?

```
    private void printDocTicket_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        float point = 60;

        for (int x = 0; x < DGVUpload.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            point += 60;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(DGV["Sym3", x].Value.ToString(), new Font("Courier New", 30), Brushes.Black, 60 , point );
            e.Graphics.DrawString(DGV["Sym4", x].Value.ToString(), new Font("Courier New", 30), Brushes.Black, 250, point);

            if (x <= DGV.Rows.Count)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying my code after coming to the realization that e.HasMorePages restarts the PrintPage event gave me the results that I was looking for.

```
int i;

private void printDocTicket_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    float point = 60;  

    e.Graphics.DrawString(DGV["Sym3", x].Value.ToString(), new Font("Courier New", 30), Brushes.Black, 60 , point );
    e.HasMorePages = true;
    i++;

    if(i == DGV.Rows.Count)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }
}
```